# Kendo Grid, using javascript to create the grid dynamically. The read event is not calling the server side controller function

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, controller, grid, server-side

I am working with Kendo Grid.  I am creating the grid dynamically and I am trying to also use the server side paging.  I setup the parameters to use the read ajax call to read data from server side controller.  But when debugging I cannot get the server side function in the controller to fire and the grid returns with no data.  Here is the javascript code on the cshtml file.

```js
function createGrid(gridColumnList);
{
    var model = createModel(gridColumnList);

    $(gridReportResults").kendoGrid({
        
        dataSource: {
            transport:{
                 read: {
                     url: "@Url.Action("GetReportResults", "Report", new { ReportId = Model.ReportId, NavId = Session.GetNavigationId() })";
                     dataType: "json",
                     contentType: "application/json",
                     type: "POST",
                     cache: false
                 }
            },
            model: model,
            type: "json"
        },
        schema: {
            data: "data",
            total: "total"
        },

        serverPaging: true,
        selectable: true,
        pageable: {
            pageSize: 250
        },
        autoBind: true,
        height: 400,
        scrollable: true,
        columns: createColumns(gridColumnList); 


    }).data("kendoGrid");
}
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you create a new instance of a kendo.data.DataSource object for the `dataSource` property instead of using a JSON object? For example, look at the last example found here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/datasource

Answer (score 0):

You've assigned a couple of properties to your grid which should have been used to configure your dataSource, namely `serverPaging` and `schema`. Also, the `model` definition belongs inside the `schema`.

You may find the [grid](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid) and [dataSource](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource) documentation useful.

Try this instead:

```
$(gridReportResults").kendoGrid({
    
    dataSource: {
        transport:{
             read: {
                 url: "@Url.Action("GetReportResults", "Report", new { ReportId = Model.ReportId, NavId = Session.GetNavigationId() })";
                 dataType: "json",
                 contentType: "application/json",
                 type: "POST",
                 cache: false
             }
        },
        schema: {
            model: model,
            data: "data",
            total: "total"
        },
        serverPaging: true,
        type: "json"
    },

    selectable: true,
    pageable: {
        pageSize: 250
    },
    autoBind: true,
    height: 400,
    scrollable: true,
    columns: createColumns(gridColumnList); 


}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will give it a try.

Comment: The grid gets created with no issues with the code I have shown above.  The only thing is, it seems to not fire the read event.  I have a breakpoint in my code on the server side and it never reaches that breakpoint.  Using Visual Studio.

Comment: So your URL is being generated server-side (presumably MVC) - does that look correct in your script when it reaches the browser? Assuming it is, does your browser ever actually issue a GET request to the server? The developer toolbar in your browser should hopefully show something (or perhaps try Fiddler to monitor traffic from your browser).